Issue with PySpark DataFrame Persistence After Calling Update Function from Main
I have developed a separate function that is called from my main function to update data in a specific table. This function takes a DataFrame as an input, performs the necessary updates, and is supposed to return control back to the main function. However, after the update function completes and returns to the main function, all DataFrames associated with the input DataFrame - such as any references that were linked to it — are unexpectedly emptied or cleared. As a result, when I try to access those DataFrames after the update, they no longer contain any data. If I am running the update function line of code directly in main there is no issue.
here my code for update function:
def update_data(input_df):
    
    try:
        """

        :param input_df: DataFrame containing new or updated records.
        """
        input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("update_data")
        # Load the existing table from Databricks
        journey_table_df = spark.table(table_location)
        print("loaded")
        journey_table_df.createOrReplaceTempView("journey_table_df")
        print("success")
        # Merge the input DataFrame with the existing DataFrame
        spark.sql(f"""
            MERGE INTO journey_table_df AS existing
            USING update_data
            ON existing.id = update_data.id
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
                    UPDATE SET *
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT *
        """)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

I tried using delta table function but it did not work. I even converted the data to pandas data frame to break the link and that did not work as well.
